# getting error as deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: c++, string-literals, bgi

I'm getting error as **deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]** at `initgraph()` function

```
// C Implementation for drawing circle 
#include <graphics.h> 

//driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    int gd = DETECT, gm; 

    initgraph(&gd, &gm, ""); //here I'm getting an error of string

    circle(250, 200, 50); 

    getch(); 

    closegraph(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question! Have you googled "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`""` is a c-style [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes) whose type is `const char[1]` and could convert to `const char*` implicitly. Implicit conversion to `char*` is not allowed since C++11.

> In C, string literals are of type `char[]`, and can be assigned directly to a (non-const) `char*`. C++03 allowed it as well (but deprecated it, as literals are `const` in C++). C++11 no longer allows such assignments without a cast.

Making `initgraph` taking `const char*` is the best. Otherwise you have to perform explicit conversion with [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast); but note that attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior. If `initgraph` would do, then you shouldn't pass a string literal.